# Laravel Migration - Data type also changes when renaming column

Tags: laravel-5.8, laravel-migrations

I want to rename the column in database using migration, but when i tried it, the datatype also changes. How to rename column without changing the data type.

The current name of the column in the database is 
**payment_amount_cash** and its type is **double(10,2)**

I tried

```
$table->renameColumn('payment_amount_cash', 'payment_amount_full')->comment('Advanced payment')->default("0.00");
```

to rename the column. Then after migration, the name was changed but the data type was also changed from **double(10,2)** to only **double** thus, making the default value change from **0.00** to **0**.

I also tried to change the data type after the schema of renaming the column.

```
$table->renameColumn('payment_amount_cash', 'payment_amount_full')->comment('Advanced payment')->default("0.00");
$table->double('payment_amount_full', 10,2)->change();
```

but this one gives me error upon migration.

```
 Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException  : Unknown column type "double" requested.
 Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). 
You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). 
If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. 
Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). 
If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

With this, I just want to know how to rename the column without affecting the data type. After migration, I would like to retain the data type of the column I just changed the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that there is an issue in Schema regarding the enum and still in discussion until now.
I just used the other way to update the datatype of the column.

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE reservations MODIFY COLUMN payment_amount_full double(10,2)');
```

and this works for me. If there are other ways on how to do this, please let me know. Thanks.